# Passing data around single file components in Vue files?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have data in my `Topbar.vue` file called `activeTab` that I want the value of to drive other components in my blade view but right now it's only in my `Topbar.vue` component.

**main-page-blade.php**

```
<div id = "app"> 
   <Topbar>dsd</Topbar>
   **** wanting to do something like this: ****
   <Account v-if="activeTab === 1"></Account>
   <Names v-if="activeTab === 2"></Names> 
   ********************************************

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/app.js">
```

**app.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('topbar', require('./components/Topbar.vue').default);

export const bus = new Vue();

new Vue({
    el: "#app"
})
```

**Topbar.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="tabs">
            <a v-on:click="handleClick(1)" v-bind:class="[ activeTab === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">Names</a>
            <a v-on:click="handleClick(2)" v-bind:class="[ activeTab === 2 ? 'active' : '' ]">Order</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        data() {

            return {
                activeTab: 1
            }
        },

        methods: {
        handleClick: function(num) {
          this.activeTab = num
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the management of activeTab inside the data() of your parent component.

To pass data from child to its parent, we use [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

So, in your `Topbar.vue`, you can implement handleClick like:

```
handleClick: function(num) {
   this.$emit('click-from-topbar', num)
}
```

And then you will be able to catch this event in your main page doing:

```
<Topbar @click-from-topbar="someMethod">dsd</Topbar>
```

Finally, you do what you need inside the parent component (main page), using:

```
someMethod: function(num) {
   this.activeTab = num
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, how does this differ from the event bus in vue?  I came across that after posting this question. ( https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860 )